# Освобождение памяти в C++

Tags: c++

Есть класс `Cinema`, а так же производные от него. В консольном приложении я создаю список этих классов.

```
auto cinemas = new std::list<Cinema*>();

cinemas->push_back(new ImaxCinema("Victory square 15/6", "Imax 1", 150, 150));
cinemas->push_back(new Cinema3D("Victory square 16/1", "3D-Cinema", "Spectrum", 14));
cinemas->push_back(new DriveInCinema("Victory square 17/89", "Drive-In", 15, 102.3));
```

Позже, с помощью цикла, я вывожу содержимое.

```
for (auto iterator = cinemas->begin(); iterator != cinemas->end(); iterator++)
{
    (*iterator)->write();
}
```

Затем очищаю список и освобождаю память выделенную под список.

```
cinemas->clear();
delete cinemas;
```

**Вопрос: вызывается ли *delete* для каждого элемента в списке? Как это можно проверить?**

Comment: Конечно, нет. Проверить? Ну добавьте в деструктор какой-то вывод, чтоб убедиться...

Comment: @Harry Каким образом тогда очищать? В цикле?

Comment: ...или использовать интеллектуальные указатели.

Comment: @Harry можно пример?

Comment: Тогда удаляйте в цикле :) Много писать, сочиняя пример, мне сейчас некогда...

Comment: Вообще есть общее правило: new и delete должны вызываться одинаковое количество раз. Иначе - либо утечка памяти, либо попытка освобождения уже освобожденной памяти.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, раз уж Вы упомянули правило, я упомяну пару исключений: вызов `delete` для указателя, инициализированного `nullptr`, placement-форма оператора `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, память неявно не освобождается. Мало того, после вызова `clear()` Вы потеряли все имеющиеся указатели и, если они нигде более не сохранены, то Вы уже не сможете освободить память.

Вы можете освободить память в цикле, перед вызовом `clear()`:

```
for (auto p: *cinemas) {
    delete p;
}
cinemas->clear();
delete cinemas;
```

Также Вы можете использовать умные указатели:

```
auto cinemas = std::make_unique<std::list<std::unique_ptr<Cinema>>>();

cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<ImaxCinema>("Victory square 15/6", "Imax 1", 150, 150));
cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<Cinema3D>("Victory square 16/1", "3D-Cinema", "Spectrum", 14));
cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<DriveInCinema>("Victory square 17/89", "Drive-In", 15, 102.3));

cinemas->clear();//"Умные" указатели уничтожат объекты, которыми владеют
cinemas.reset();//Удаление объекта, которым владеет cinemas
//Или совсем ничего не нужно вызывать, объект будет уничтожен при выходе из области видимости
```

Answer (score 2):

Формально педантично-правильный способ удаления элементов из контейнера "голых" указателей должен выглядеть примерно так

```
while (!cinemas->empty())
{
  Cinema *cinema = сinemas->back();
  cinemas->pop_back();
  delete cinema;
}

delete cinemas;
```

Идея заключается в том, чтобы ни в какой момент времени в контейнере не хранились невалидные указатели. Т.е. в первую очередь удаляется элемент из контейнера, и только затем уничтожается объект, на который этот элемент указывал.

Вариант, который начинает с удаления всех указуемых объектов и только потом удаляет элементы списка, является практически приемлемым для `std::list<>`, но запросто может привести к проблемам с другими типами контейнеров (в частности, с ассоциативными контейнерами).

Answer (score 1):

1. Удалять вручную.

   ```
   for(auto cinema: *cinemas) delete cinema;
   cinemas->clear();
   ```
2. Заставить компилятор сделать это за вас:

   ```
   auto cinemas = new std::list<std::unique_ptr<Cinema>>();

   cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<ImaxCinema>("Victory square 15/6", "Imax 1", 150, 150));
   cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<Cinema3D>("Victory square 16/1", "3D-Cinema", "Spectrum", 14));
   cinemas->push_back(std::make_unique<DriveInCinema>("Victory square 17/89", "Drive-In", 15, 102.3));
   cinemas->clear();
   ```

PS. А `cinemas` должен быть указателем?

Comment: Почему `cinemas` не должен быть указателем?